# Why is my Visual Studio Code workspaceStorage directory so large?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, redhat

I'm on MacOs Mojave.

When I browse to  `/../Code/User/WorkspaceStorage/../redhat.java`
I noticed that the directory appears to have a copy of my whole desktop folder contained within it.

I was wondering if it was safe to delete it, what might have caused this, and how/if I can prevent this from happening again.

These are the java extensions I have installed:

- Debugger for Java
- Extension Pack for Java
- Project Manager for Java
- Test Runner for Java
- Language Support for Java(TM)by RedHat

I also have some C++ extensions.

I've figured out that it might be that Language Support for Java saved my desktop files to see any changes in the workspace since I've previously saved some .java files on my desktop.

Comment: What problem are you having now? What effect do you expect to get? Can you describe the problem in more detail so others can help you solve it.

Comment: I deleted the folder and I dont save any .java file directly on desktop

Comment: So is your problem still there? Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).